# Use a class to update data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched for this topic, and can't find anything that answers my needs, so I am assuming I may be looking at this the wrong way. Keep in mind, I was a classic ASP developer for 13 years, so I am used to having control over all of my code.

I have many forms on my sites for updating data: Customer information, Supplier information, Product information, User information, etc., etc. I used a library I wrote which made it easy to simply build a form, set the values, and it created the update script automatically. However, in ASP.Net, it just doesn't seem this is the way to do it.

ASP.Net, seems to have wizards. Personally, I don't like that approach. I like full control. I don't even like the ASP.Net validation controls...

**Option 1:** Build classes with update methods. Build a standard ASP.Net form, which will update the data through the class?

**Option 2:** Use the annoying GridViews, DataAdapters, wizards, etc., etc.

**Option 3:** Standard form, with AJAX, calling a WebMethod with the class to update data.

Which approach is most standard now (or most practical)? Which one has the best control as well as security? I don't like wizards, and I like to know exactly what's going on, so when something "doesn't go on", I can figure out why without going through a wizard. I want to be efficient with creating forms, so I can create them quickly but still have the flexibility to customize and control what's going on from user interface, to validation, to security.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms. It gives you much more  fine-tuned control over the HTML content you produce, but at the same time it has some very flexible and powerful features that make it easy to perform common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at things like `FormView` and `DetailsView`. They work with data source controls like the `SqlDataSource` control to automatically generate the SQL to interact with the database. No code involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a ASP Classic library, can you not just port that to a .Net library and continue using it.  If you have code that works and you are happy with it no need to throw it away just because it might not be exactly the "correct path"

Comment: Good point. I guess the difference is the way I now connect to SQL server, and run scripts. It's more secure this way. I ended up doing something similar to what I did before, except in .Net. I was just more efficient in Classic ASP than I am in .Net. I love .Net, don't get me wrong, but it's definitely not ALWAYS more efficient (coding-wise).